# How to acess spring data redis stored object at the expiration event?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am storing a Cart in Redis using Spring Data Redis for a specific time. An expiration property annotated with @TimeToLive sets the time to live for the Cart object as described by the code below.
I have set `KeyExpirationEventMessageListener` type to listen to the expiration event in order to process additional work at the expiration event. I was able to fetch the key from the triggered event of the expiration object and I am trying to access it or its phantom object at the expiry time using the spring data repository but with no result.It returns an empty object which means that the original obeject is likely been deleted. I don't know if it is the proper way to do it.But, is there a way to fetch the expiry object at expiration or just before it gets deleted to process motre work?

```
@RedisHash("cart")
public class Cart implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Indexed
    private String id;
    private long customerId;
    private Set<CartLine> lines = new HashSet<>();

    @TimeToLive
    private long expiration;

}

public interface ShoppingCartRepository extends CrudRepository<Cart, String> {

}


    @Component
    public class RedisKeyExpirationListener extends KeyExpirationEventMessageListener {

        private RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate;
        private ShoppingCartRepository repository;
        public RedisKeyExpirationListener(RedisMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer,
                                          RedisTemplate redisTemplate, ShoppingCartRepository repository) {
            super(listenerContainer);
            this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
            this.repository = repository;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
            String key = new String(message.getBody());
            try {
                String id = extractId(key);
                Optional<ShoppingCart> cart = repository.findById(id);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                logger.info("something went wrong  ====>  " + e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
        private String extractId(String key){
            String keyPrefix = ShoppingCart.class.getAnnotation(RedisHash.class).value();
            return key.substring((keyPrefix + ":").length());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Example using Spring boot 2.3.4.RELEASE

```java
@RedisHash("cart")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Cart implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Indexed
    private String id;
    private String customerName;
    @TimeToLive
    private long expiration;
}
```

```java
public interface ShoppingCartRepository extends CrudRepository<Cart, String> {
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP)
public class RedisExpirationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RedisExpirationApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(ShoppingCartRepository shoppingCartRepository) {
        return args -> {
            // TTL 1 second
            shoppingCartRepository.save(new Cart("some-id", "My Customer Name", 1));
            // wait 5 seconds
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        };
    }

    @Component
    public class CartListener {
        // need to enable redis notifications, inside redis-cli type:
        // config set notify-keyspace-events KEA
        @EventListener
        public void anything(RedisKeyExpiredEvent<Cart> expiredCart) {
            Cart cart = (Cart) expiredCart.getValue();
            System.out.println(cart.getId());
            System.out.println(cart.getCustomerName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nilzao, very well integrated with Spring Boot 2.3.4. This works perfectly fine.

Comment: @ROUISSIMohamedALi did you enable keyspace events in code using the attribute `enableKeyspaceEvents` or manually from Redis console?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I did it manually from the Redis console.

Answer (score 0):

There was once a use case in my scenario, you can actually use RedisKeyExpiredEvent,

- RedisKeyExpiredEvent [0] is a Redis specific ApplicationEvent published
  when a particular key in Redis expires. It can hold the value of the
  expired key next to the key.

You can proceed with the following implementaion.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRedisRepositories(considerNestedRepositories = true, enableKeyspaceEvents = EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP)
static class Config {

    /**
     * An {@link ApplicationListener} that captures {@link RedisKeyExpiredEvent}s and just prints the value to the
     * console.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    ApplicationListener<RedisKeyExpiredEvent<Person>> eventListener() {
        return event -> {
            System.out.println(String.format("Received expire event for key=%s with value %s.",
                    new String(event.getSource()), event.getValue()));
        };
    }
}
```

You can find the sample implementation at [1].

> 

- [0] https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisKeyExpiredEvent.html#getValue--
- [1] https://github.com/christophstrobl/next-level-redis-with-spring/blob/master/src/test/java/org/example/repository/RepsoitoryTests.java#L57

Comment: I have added ```@EnableRedisRepositories(considerNestedRepositories = true, enableKeyspaceEvents = EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP)```on top of the starter class and add eventListener() Bean with my custom cart object.But when it expires the lambda function does not get called. I have tried to use it as a component as well but ```onApplicationEvent``` method does not get called

Comment: Did you tried to debug properly, Are you sure code is properly implemented. Could you give me any logs or sample implementation where I can check it running on my local instance.

Comment: Yeah I have tried with debug as well. Here is a sample code base that is nit working https://bitbucket.org/marouissi/springdataredis/src/master/

Comment: Hey Anuj did you get the chance to see this code example. Were you able to make it work